# Is it possible to change the full url using .htaccess or javascript?

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to reverse the **full** url of my website:

www.example.com 
into
moc.elpmaxe.www

I have managed to change the url after the hash by using window.document.location.hash in javascript and the mod_rewrite function of .htaccess, ending up with something like: www.example.com/#moc.elpmaxe.www

I assume it's impossible for security reasons or because moc.elpmaxe.www is not a valic url. But if there are some possibilities it would be great.

my .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index.html\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /moc.elpmaxe.www [R=301,L]
```

the javascript I used:

```
window.document.location.hash = "lmth.xedni\moc.elpmaxe.www";
```

Answer (score 2):

I highly doubt it's possible to do, because if it was possible, there would already be sites using this to spoof as other websites.

For example it could change it's url from `www.badsite.com` to `www.superrealbank.com`